# PHP Redirect using basename(__FILE__) not working in Windows Apache server

Tags: php, redirect, using

I am building web application in Windows 7 OS running Apache Server, PHP 5.3 with MySQL.

This redirect doesn't work

```
    <?php
    // this is the path
    // C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Biohouse\member\public\index.php

    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'\public\index.php';
    header("location: $path");


while this working

$path = '/public/index.php'
```

But i will like to use the first method. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Its a known fact that to preserve cross-platform compatiblity , back slash should usually be used. Why do you prefer the first method instead?

Comment: you are not making the difference between a physical path (like c:\apache\htdocs\) and an url (like http://localhost)

Comment: i use str_replace and the entire \ replace to / but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dirname(__FILE__)` gives you the path to the folder within the local file system, whereas `/public/index.php` is a path within the document root of the webserver/vhost of the webserver. You just *cannot* use `__FILE__` to create URLs.

Comment: So what should i do in this case? In MVC we use dirname().

Comment: The problem is not `dirname()`, but `__FILE__`. If you `echo` `__FILE__` you'll notice, that it is the filepath on the filesystem. But "the webservers world" begin at the document root. You can try to strip the document root from the absolute path you'll get from `__FILE__´. This may work as long as you don't use `mod_rewrite`, or similar. (Sidenote: "MVC" is a pattern...)

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'\public\index.php'; header("location: $path");
```

Have a look at PHPs magical constants here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: you are doing basically the exact same mistake; take a look at http://php.net/dirname that function returns a path, not an url.. it's like instead of redirecting an user to google you would redirect them to /home/html/bla/bla/bla/

Comment: Or like "Hey, please click on my link `<a href="file:///etc/passwd">x</a>`

Comment: Sorry. I only saw the post without the code formatting. The first thing I've noticed was `FILE` instead of `__FILE__`